# PhotoCell circuit with identity

Tags: embedded, arduino

I have a photocell that gives me the intensity of light in voltage. I want to add a unique number (that I can hard-code on the chip) along with the photocell info and send in a format I can read using a digital computer (Arduino). Any suggestion when I can start?

Comment: you want the unique number in the arduino (use the flash) our outside?  If outside in the photocell (does it have a unique number or storage for such a thing)?  You can look up dallas semiconductor, well now maxim and get some flavor of one wire device, each has a unique number, build that into the circuit and use that unique number along with the photocell reading.   The easiest would probably be put the serial number in the avr.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to shop for a cheap micro controller that's easy to work with, has an ADC, and a small amount of flash memory.  Almost every silicon vendor will claim to have something meeting that requirement, what you are familiar with and can easily buy in appropriate quantities may matter as much as the technical details of the offering.  If you already have an arduino, another atmel part such as one of the 8-pin attiny's might be attractive.

You write a little program with a loop that reads the photocell through the ADC, bundles it with an ID number which you store in the flash beside your program, and ships it off through something like a serial port to whatever system needs the information.

Serial port can be a UART peripheral or bit-banged in a software timing loop.  For short runs people often skip the line driver/receiver on each end and signal at logic voltage rather than the higher voltage (and inverted sense, the drivers/receivers invert for you) of the RS232 spec.  Or you can use other schemes, synchronous ones like SPI or I2C being popular as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at maxim one-wire bus devices.

They share a bus connection and ground and your ardunio can interrogate the bus.

Each device has a unique identifer and can be read.

The DS2438 is a cheap member of the family that can measure voltage.

(The DS2450 was a quad A/D converter but it was a buggy chip and is now obsolete.)

Ardunio drivers at http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Learning/OneWire